# Получить параметр из уведомления в нужную Activity

Tags: android, firebase

Доброго времени суток!

Отправляю уведомление firebase через php с параметрами:

```
    $notification = [
                'title' =>'Заголвок',
                'body' => 'Сообщение',
                'icon' =>'ic', 
                'sound' => 'mySound',
                'click_action' => 'ACTIVITY_LTK'
            ];
 // тут данные, которые необходимо передать в Activity
            $extraNotificationData = [
            "message" => $notification,
            "method" =>'calling',
            "url" =>'site.com'
            ];
```

Манифест

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LtkActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTIVITY_LTK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

При клике на уведомление, открывается нужное мне Activity, но как я могу получить отправленные параметры method и url?

Comment: Попробуйте получить данные из `intent.getData()`, который будет аргументом  переопределённого в активити метода `onNewIntent()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог следующий код:

```
JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");
int destination = payload.getInt("click_action");

Intent resultIntent;
resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("url", url);
```